# Hive Partitioned, Bucketed and Sorted table - multiple inserts

Tags: apache-spark, hive, query-optimization

Hello and apologies for a long text,

We use hive 1.2.0 and have table partitioned by date, bucketed by customer id and sorted by customer id as well. (I know, it shouldn't be sorted per same thing, but it made sense to do it).

When we tested performance, we used already existing table, so each partition had 128 files (table had 128 buckets). Performance impact was great.

I noticed however that in real time environment, all inserts create additional 128 files. I was expecting to see Hive insert into already existing files. If we fill the table hourly, we could then expect 24 x 128 files, all sorted. But this is not really sorted any more - it's *per file sorted*. I'm sure it still counts, but it's going to take a hit at performance. Table had ~100M daily rows. And due to some subsequent / late entries, actual number of inserts into one partition could be larger than 24 - it could be 30-40.

We're currently looking at doing weekly *compaction* jobs, but it's really depressing :). Initially, this was a Spark pipeline, then required Hive inserting from a "Spark staging table" since Spark cannot write to such table, and now we're looking at the possibility of having a *compaction* job...

Any comments / suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get what you are exactly trying to ask.

But as per your question.

- It is good idea that you created the sorted buckets on customer id it
  will sure give performance optimizations and mainly in joins like SMB
  and bucketed joins you will see great improvement.
- It is known that if you insert into buckted table hive will create
  new buckets with **_copy** it will not edit or update the existing
  bucket instead it will create a new bucket with new values.

  if you are at the designing phase of your application I would suggest you to create 1 more partition clause based on techincal partition that can be your run id.
  For example if you are running your process hourly so you can create your new partition based on hour or it can be any unique id that you can generate

So your directly structure will be like

```
table_name/<date>/<hour>/bucketes_files
```

There is no way you can edit the existing buckets.

**Other workaround is along with your main table create a temporary table what will hold you data for 1 day or so and join this table with new data and insert overwrite the main table in that way your bucktes will hold the all sorted customer_id and and there will be no copy of files as we are insert overwriting the data into existing table**

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid I'll see something like this. The problem is - like mentioned in my long question - that we keep receiving data for particular day even the next one or two days. Very unfortunate thing indeed. My idea is to go on with compaction idea then - I'll simply create a weekly job that will run on weekend and copy data from e.g. two weeks ago, drop all from original table and then write it back in one go. Thanks for the answer. I'll accept it as answer very soon - just want to keep hoping for some time still :)

Comment: Yes agreed compaction is also a good idea in your scenario. Just important pointer before considering this. while daily loading data into your main table create another table that will hold the data for some duration also may be 15 days. So as to prepare for worst case scenario during compaction. And there is 1 more way to do is create two table 1 which will hold the data as it is means(duplicate buckets) and create another table  with same structure that will insert overwrite from table1 whenever data comes into table 1 or daily or after certain invetervals may be weekly in your processing.

Comment: Agreed - I'm definitely going to make a backup before removing. But I still find it weir Hive doesn't offer this functionality...

Comment: Hive have its limitations, but it make sense that how complex and time taking process it would be to edit existing(buckets) and searching,sorting and compare each new key(customer_id) with data in file and inserting at exact location in existing very large files.